# Select value from table where the name is stored in another table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have below view which uses `get_rationalized_ip_adr` function to retrieve some value given as input the nodeid from NODE table.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW A_DEVICE AS
    SELECT  NODE.NAME AS DEVICE
          , NODETYPE.TABLENAME AS TABLENAME
          , ext_a_device.get_rationalized_ip_adr(NODE.NODEID) AS IPADDRESS
          , COALESCE(LOC_SITE.OS_EASTING, LOC_RAILWAY.OS_EASTING, LOC_SIGNALBOX.EASTING) AS OS_EASTING
          , COALESCE(LOC_SITE.OS_NORTHING, LOC_RAILWAY.OS_NORTHING, LOC_SIGNALBOX.NORTHING) AS OS_NORTHING
    FROM NODE NODE
    JOIN NODETYPE NODETYPE
    ON NODE.NODE2NODETYPE = NODETYPE.NODETYPEID;
```

I had to add the function in the select stmt in order to get ipaddresses that are present in some other tables, tables which have the name stored in `NODETYPE` table.

For example this is a screen shot form nodetype table. So the `get_rationalized_ip_adr` calls an API that does the fetching from `NR_NODE_DDF` for each nodeid passed to it.

[image]

`get_rationalized_ip_adr` function just calls an API with the nodeid input and returns the ip_adr for the respective node.

```
FUNCTION get_rationalized_ip_adr( pin_node_id IN NUMBER)

RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
ln_errorcode NUMBER;
ls_errortext VARCHAR2(200);
ls_result    VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    pkggeneral.getobjectattribute( o_errorcode => ln_errorcode
                                        , o_errortext => ls_errortext
                                        , i_dimobject => pkgdimensionconstants.dimensionObject_Node
                                        , i_objectid  => pin_node_id
                                        , i_attribute => 'IP_ADDRESS'
                                        , o_result    => ls_result);
    RETURN ls_result;
END get_rationalized_ip_adr;
```

Now the problem for example is that this select statement is taking around 90 seconds, which is too much.

```
SELECT * FROM A_DEVICE ad where ad.ipaddress = '10.16.52.152'
```

As I understood switching between sql and pl-sql context is the problem of this time to run.

Can anyone think of another solution to decrease this time??

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your function call with join with a table which stores IP addresses.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW A_DEVICE AS
    SELECT  NODE.NAME AS DEVICE
          , NODETYPE.TABLENAME AS TABLENAME
          , t.IPADDRESS
          , COALESCE(LOC_SITE.OS_EASTING, LOC_RAILWAY.OS_EASTING, LOC_SIGNALBOX.EASTING) AS OS_EASTING
          , COALESCE(LOC_SITE.OS_NORTHING, LOC_RAILWAY.OS_NORTHING, LOC_SIGNALBOX.NORTHING) AS OS_NORTHING
    FROM NODE NODE
    JOIN NODETYPE NODETYPE
         ON NODE.NODE2NODETYPE = NODETYPE.NODETYPEID
    join table_with_ip_address t
         on ...;
```

Also, make sure you have required indexes on fields which you use for the join.

Comment: Yes, but the table names to join to are stored in another table - `NODETYPE`, I can't do a direct join

Comment: You want to say you have several tables to store IP address? Not very good idea. If there is no possibility to merge them into one, use `union all`.

Comment: Yes that's right, there are several tables for each nodetype, from original design of the app, I'll try then with `union all`

Comment: I made some `LEFT JOIN`s and a `COALESCE` on the ip_address column and it works, but if I add a new table I need to add also a new `LEFT JOIN` and a `COALESCE` condition so maybe there is a cleaner solution

Comment: @AndreiMaieras The cleaner solution is to get rid of bad database design and store all IPs in one table.

Comment: I see :) back in 2007 when the db was designed they were not thinking on this, thanks Dmitry